# how to build a professional help to the website?

Tags: .net, asp.net, html-helper, helper

Q:

I wanna to make a **Help** to my
   website ,, but i wanna this help to
   be in a professional way,i ask about
   the basic elements that supposed to
   be in this help, any
   recommendations,suggestions,thoughts
   about how to build this HELP please..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think this would vary immensely depending on the website. You should give us more information about the site itself if you want good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .Net Applications:

- [Integrate Help Into Your .NET Apps](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/HelpIntegrationInDotNet.aspx)

You can use jquery plugins to show Help in Dialogs when user click help links:

- [15+ jQuery Popup Modal Dialog Plugins and Tutorials](http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/)

You can also use tootips to provide help when hover on different section of your webpage:

- [30 Stylish jQuery Tooltip Plugins For Catchy Designs](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/)

You can also provide online help to your visitors:

- [Live Chat Software For ASP.NET](http://cutesoft.net/live-support/)
- [How to Add a Skype Call Me Button to a Web site](http://www.ehow.com/how_2015381_skype-call-me-button.html)

Comment: this is really great help for my help..thanks a lot but i can say all of them are tools to build my help ,, if u can tell me some points should i take care as instructions whan building my help to be as comprehensive and professional as possible..really thanks alot.

Comment: @just_name: It depends on the nature of your site. In case of tooltips, you should not use extra large tooltips. Use simple language. Show different process in the form of bullets and numbers. You can provide separate webpage to show help topics for your whole site category wise. For example: http://www.google.com/support/   http://www.facebook.com/help/

Answer (score 1):

Video tutorials are always helpful, walking them through the site and typical usage.